# Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot when connected to ASUS ROG XG32VQR screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, visual-artifacts

My system has been running on my AsRock B550M for a couple of months running Ubuntu 22.04. As of Wed 9th August the system now no longer boots when connected to my Asus XG32VQR monitor. I have 2 of these monitors and have tested on both leading to the same outcome. When Ubuntu boots it displays a recovering journal message and then clearing orphan inode, then the display below this appears corrupted. clearing orphaned inode message appears even when the system was cleanly shutdown the last time it shutdown. I have been able to connect a different screen and the system boots no display issues every time, even after intentionally performing an unclean shutdown. I have included an example of the graphical visual artifacts here.

[image: example of the graphical corruption]

I have confirmed that I do not have Nvidia drivers installed on this system.

System specs are as follows:

- MB: AsRock B550M Steel Legend
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600x
- RAM: 16GB G.Skill
- OS Drive: Intel 660p 500GB
- GPU: Asus Nvidia 730 GT
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04